I can't access Lombok's AllArgsContructor when I extend RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport
I've been trying to solve it for a while but I couldn't find anything to help me, in my Spring Boot Project, in one of the assembler classes I extend "RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport", when I extend the class I start to have a conflict with my Lombok @AllArgsContructor, I use it to not use @Autowired keeping the code clean, so I can't compile, and I get the following Warning in the annotation "Lombok needs a default constructor in the base class", but I already have a constructor in the Class
After a lot of research, I saw that in some cases other annotations like @NoArgsConstructor and @RequiredArgsConstructor helped but I was not successful.
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SaleModelAssembler
        extends RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport<Sale, SaleModel> {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public SaleModelAssembler() {
        super(SaleResource.class, SaleModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public SaleModel toModel(Sale sale) {
        SaleModel saleModel = createModelWithId(sale.getCode(), sale);

        modelMapper.map(sale, saleModel);

        saleModel.getItems().forEach(saleItemModel -> {
            saleItemModel.getProduct().add(linkTo(ProductResource.class)
                    .slash(saleItemModel.getProduct().getId()).withSelfRel());
        });

        return saleModel;
    }

    @Override
    public CollectionModel<SaleModel> toCollectionModel(Iterable<? extends Sale> entities) {
        return super.toCollectionModel(entities).add(linkTo(SaleResource.class).withSelfRel());
    }
}



In newest spring you no longer need  Autowired whith AllArgsConstuctor

Lombok can't call the super constructor of a class (how to Call super constructor in Lombok), so the annotations you are using can't do the job.
If you want not to use the @Autowired annotation, you can try this:
@Component
public class SaleModelAssembler extends RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport<Sale, SaleModel> {

  private ModelMapper modelMapper;

  public SaleModelAssembler(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    super(SaleResource.class, SaleModel.class);
    this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
  }


I really didn't want to use an autowired in a project where I use Lombok, I think it's a bit out of hand, thanks for the help, it worked the way I wanted, thanks
